# What are the correct values for relativistic 3-momentum $p=mv$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, momentum, mass

Is the value of $m$ in this formula relativistic mass or real mass? Just trying to figure out if this is the right equation for my problem.

Comment: There is no relativistic mass. It's time to get rid of that nonsensical idea. The formula for the momentum is $p = \gamma m v$ where $m$ is the (rest) mass of the object.

Comment: "There is no relativistic mass" is an unscientific statement. Whether there is relativistic mass or not depends on your definition of mass.

Comment: @md2perpe : The concept of relativistic mass has been abandoned in contemporary Physics.

Comment: @Frobenius. Not using the concept of relativistic mass is quite different from saying that there is no relativistic mass.

Comment: I would say that using it is terrible teaching practice and irresponsible.  It is misleading; read this site to see why!  People answering questions here should know better.

Comment: Downvoted for use of term 'relativistic mass'

Comment: [Why is there a controversy on whether mass increases with speed?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/133376/123208)

Comment: @PM2Ring there is _no_ controversy whatsoever; mass does _not_ increase with speed!  If you disagree, give a _physical mechanism_ for this to happen.

Comment: Gravitational mass doesn't change between different inertial frames. At high velocities inertial mass stops being equal to the gravitational mass

Comment: @m4r35n357 I most certainly *don't* disagree! I linked that post because the top answer there (by Ben Crowell) is excellent.

Comment: @PM2Ring Of course I recognize your nick, please pardon my directness ;)  But it seems there is so much residual "controversy" here about all this that I needed to make the point about the title.  There are _not_ two sides to this argument.

Comment: The title of that question is a little unfortunate, but Ben forcefully insists that there *is* no controversy... unless you're stuck in some kind of time warp. In which case, you probably think that "modern music" means The Beatles. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring I like Tsamparlis' approach to this!

Answer (score 3):

The four-momentum has $E/c=p^0=\gamma m_0c,\,p^i=\gamma m_0c\beta^i$ if $m_0\ne0$, but $E/c=p^0,\,p^i=E\beta^i$ whether or not $m_0=0$.

Comment: Downvoted for use of the term 'relativistic mass' .

Comment: @JunSeo-He Thanks; fixed.

Answer (score 1):

> p = mv

> Is the value of m in this formula relativistic mass or real mass?

In your formula, $m$ is the "relativistic mass," not the rest mass (or "real mass" as you say).

If the rest mass is denoted as $m_0$ then
$$
p = \gamma m_0 v\;,
$$
where $v=\frac{dx}{dt}$ and $\gamma = 1/\sqrt{1-v^2/c^2}$.